# Best resources for learning xaml for Windows Store Apps?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm looking for books, online tutorials, articles, training videos and any kind of resource to learn XAML for Windows Store App. I want to master XAML to build powerful Apps. For that reason I will appreciate any helpful information.

Keep it coming!

**Summary**

Training

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229512)

[generaionapp.com](http://www.generationapp.com)

Blogs

[31 Days of Windows 8](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/category/31-days-of-windows-8/)

Code Samples

[MSDN Windows 8 app samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples)

Books

[Building Windows 8 Apps with C# and XAML (Microsoft Windows Development Series). Jeremy Likness](http://www.amazon.es/Building-Windows-Microsoft-Development-ebook/dp/B009WQ44Q4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1353535263&sr=8-1)

Incoming Books

[Programming Windows®, 6th Edition. Charles Petzold](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145369079.do)

Tools

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#express-win8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like following series

[31 Days of Windows 8](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/category/31-days-of-windows-8/)

Also I think [Generation App](http://www.generationapp.com/#fbid=nDXPjlKGKNl) have some good resources and even offers free 1 On 1 app consultation.

One of the best resource for me have been [Windows 8 app samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples), it is really helpful to use these examples, although not all the examples are straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

My book, Building Windows 8 Apps with C# and XAML (I'm avoiding posting a "vanity link" on purpose, but you should find it easily by searching on the title) has an entire chapter devoted to XAML that I believe is quite thorough.

Comment: It looks very practical. I will get a sample from Amazon. Thanks for your recomendation!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend this book from Charles Petzold:
[Programming Windows®, 6th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145369079.do)

It contains basic guides, how to use and write XAML code, how to work with the page layout, use styles and templates, etc. Currently it's available as a preview for discounted price. The final book is expected at the beginning of the next year.

Comment: Fatastic! I learned a lot from a C# book he wrote. It woth the waiting.

Answer (score 1):

I think the very best resource for learning a new tech is to write some code with it.  The most helpful learning mechanism that I used was the Contoso Cookbook hands-on lab, which walks you through building most of the new features for Windows Store apps.  You can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29854.  Choose the Win8CS.Setup.exe download for C# and XAML.

You will need Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8; you can download it free from http://aka.ms/JenVS2012 (halfway down the page, in blue).

Finally, [Generation App](http://aka.ms/JenGenApp) contains a program designed to help you learn to [write a Windows Store app in 30 days](http://aka.ms/Jen30TLWin8).  Each day you will get an email that gives you the next step, so you can step-by-step learn to build an app.  There are also free design consultations and tech support available through the program.

Answer (score 1):

Time for an up-to-date answer:

C# Refresh:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/01/free-c-training-for-beginners-and.html

Blend training:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/01/the-most-comprehensive-blend-for-visual.html

Beginning XAML:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/02/more-free-training-developing-windows.html

Universal Apps:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/10/ready-to-learn-developing-universal.html

There's more here:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/p/learn.html

Best of luck!